# Polling for external state transitions in Cadence workflows

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

I have a Cadence workflow where I need to poll an external AWS API until a particular resource transitions, which might take some amount of time. I assume I should make each individual 'checkStatus' request an Activity, and have the workflow perform the sleep/check loop. However, that means that I may have an unbounded number of activity calls in my workflow history. Is that worrisome? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how frequently you want to poll.

- For infrequent polls (every minute or slower) use the server side retry. Specify a [RetryPolicy](https://github.com/uber-go/cadence-client/blob/c3cd9f8f9745172572659a28ad1b478c19596def/internal/activity.go#L107) (or [RetryOptions](https://github.com/uber/cadence-java-client/blob/1b2a2ce0de2bc92a609080186009dd793920b46c/src/main/java/com/uber/cadence/activity/ActivityOptions.java#L141) for Java) when invoking the activity. In the RetryPolicy specify an exponential coefficient of 1 and an initial interval of the poll frequency. Then fail the activity in case the polled resource is not ready and the server is going to retry it up to the specified retry policy expiration interval.
- For very frequent polls of every few seconds or faster the solution is to implement the polling inside an activity implementation as a loop that polls and then sleeps for the poll interval. To ensure that the polling activity is restarted in a timely manner in case of worker failure/restart the activity has to heartbeat on every iteration. Use an appropriate RetryPolicy for the restarts of such failed activity.
- In a rare case when the polling requires a periodic execution of a sequence of activities or activity arguments should change between retries a child workflow can be used. The trick is that a parent is not aware about a child calling *continue as new*. It only gets notified when a child completes or fails. So if a child executes the sequence of activities in a loop and calls continue as new periodically the parent is not affected until the child completes.